# 'WinError: The remote computer refused the network connection' is caused from BitTorrent project

Tags: python, connection, bittorrent

I'm currently building a torrenting client - effectively allowing users to download torrent files following the official BitTorrent protocol. When trying to test my project with torrent files, I find that almost every file I find online results in the following error:

```
ConnectionRefusedError: [WinError 1225] The remote computer refused the network connection
```

Some things I've attempted to solve the issue

- Different internet connections
- Different torrent files from different websites
- Different torrent clients with the same files

What I still should try

- Testing the same files on a different computer

Is there any suggestion or solution to this problem? Thanks in advance

Edit:
The actual line that causes the issue itself is from when I attempt to open the connection with the peer using asyncio's `open_connection` function.

This is the line that causes the error:

```
self.reader, self.writer = await asyncio.open_connection(self.peer.host,
```

Comment: Have you tried with an existing torrent client, just to get a comparison point if it works at all?

Comment: @the8472 just tested with another bitTorrent clone from GitHub that I found. it seems to work perfectly with the same file. For further context, I'm going to edit the post with exactly what line causes the error. Seems to be from opening the connection in asyncio